# python 3.6 get text from list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am an absolute beginner, but I have managed to make a working script out of some existing scripts and tutorials. Only one thing I would like to have, unfortunately I can not do that.

So far, I'm getting data from a website that is, for example, "http://www.example.com/01536496/.../". Now I have a list (.csv or .txt) with many other numbers in the first column (or in txt-file each number in a new row). Now I want to scrape the web data for all the numbers in the list, so "http://www.example.com/No_1/.../", "http://www.example.com/No_2/.../" and so on.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import datetime

my_url = 'http://www.example.com/104289633/.../'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

...
```

**Update**

For example I have a numbers.txt with: 05543486 3468169 36189994

Now I want to put each number into the url...

Please can someone help me. I would be very grateful.

**Update**

After trying to use the code from Andersson...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import datetime

# Get list of numbers
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
    numbers = content.split()

# Handle each URL in a loop
for number in numbers:
    my_url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/%s#/' %number

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

print(my_url)

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find_all("div", {"class":"grid-item padding-desk-right-xl desk-two-thirds lap-one-whole desk-column-left flex-item palm--flex__order--1 lap--flex__order--1"})

filename = "results_"+current_datetime+".csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "titel##adresse##criteria##preis##energie##beschreibung##ausstattung##lage\n"

f.write(headers)

...

    f.write(titel + "##" + adresse + "##" + criteria.replace("    ", "; ") + "##" + preis.replace("    ", "; ") + "##" + energie.replace("    ", "; ") + "##" + beschreibung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + ausstattung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + lage.replace("\n", " ") + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you want to extract the numbers from .txt file into Python list or what?

Comment: For example i have a numbers.txt with:
05543486
3468169
36189994
Now i want to put each number into the url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code:

```
# Get list of numbers
with open("/path/to/numbers.txt") as f:
    content = f.read()
    numbers = content.split()

# Handle each URL in a loop
for number in numbers:
    url = 'http://www.example.com/%s' % number
    # Do something with url
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works only for the first number in the file. I thing i need to made a loop (?), but (i'm really sorry, that i didn't mentioned it at the first time) how can i do this? i said, i'm a absolutly beginner :-/

Comment: More loops? What for? With my code you should be able to iterate through all the numbers... Check what is the output of `print(numbers)`. Is it a list of all your numbers?

Comment: You are right, it prints all numbers, put my output (the webcrawling) has only content from the first url with the first number

Comment: Do you get the same output `N` times where `N` is the number of numbers in .txt file or you get output only once?

Comment: no i get the right output. six numbers in the file and this six numbers are the output. But i have to corrct me: i got the result of the url with the last (not first) number into the txt-file

Comment: Oh.. You mean you're writing the output of your scraping into the .txt file, right? Make sure you're using `"a"` instead of `"w"` type, e.g. `with open("file.txt", "a") as f:...` Note that `"w"` means *write into file, but remove all previous content* while `"a"` means *append new content and preserve previous*

Comment: no. I have a txt-file with numbers for different URLs. And the output of the py-script are some datas from the URLs (each number makes a new URL) in a new created csv-file. And with your code, my output is only the scraped data from the URL with the last number from the txt-file.

Comment: Anyway, I'm quite sure that the problem is the same: your previous data is replaced by new data on each iteration

Comment: sorry, you know i'm new here, how can i show you the whole code now? Edit my question?

Comment: Edit question with the part for handling/saving the output

Comment: is maybe the "#/" at the end of the URL the problem? Do i need the "s" after %? But i've tryed with and without...

Comment: You should put the code starting from `uClient = uReq(my_url)` into `for` loop on the same indentation level as `url = 'http://www.example.com/%s' % number`...

Comment: The loop works. Thanks a lot. Now i think i have to open a new question, because my ouput is not as "nice" as i hoped. For one line it shows fine, but more lines are "unsorted".

Comment: Cool! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in case it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that runs a for loop and update the url on each iteration through the loop. As the argument, you can pass the list of numbers. For example:

```
def scrape(numbers):
    for num in numbers:
        my_url = 'http://www.example.com/No_' + str(num) + '/.../'

        uClient = uReq(my_url)
        page_html = uClient.read()
        uClient.close()

        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


numbers_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
scrape(numbers_list)
```

Comment: Yes i searched for something like this, but the numbers are some specific numbers from a external .txt oder .csv file. I think instead of
numbers_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i have to open and read the file? But how?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by appending the numbers at the end of your url with a basic for loop ? I am not sure if this is what you need.

```
...

with open('yourFile', 'r') as numbersFile:
    nums = numbers.readlines()

for num in nums:
    url = "http://www.example.com/No_" + num + "/.../"
    # do what you want to do with the url...
```

Comment: Yes but i want to put specific numbers from a external file. Each number in a row of the file.

Comment: @JuliGoe edited the code, this question is probably answered before, you need to search it.

Answer (score 0):

## Load from csv file

You can iterate over the file rows in various ways, but what I think is the most clean one is by using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/).
You just need to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

# assuming that filename.csv's first line has a header called "Numbers"
# You can apply a function `func` to each element of the column via `map`
df['Numbers'].map(func)
```

## Urls from Numbers

Using pandas' `map` function, we can pass each value to a function to create our url.

```
# First of all, we define this function
def numberToUrl(number):
    # We can use python's `string.format()` to format a string
    return 'http://www.example.com/{}/.../'.format(number)

# Then we can pass this function to each value with `map`
# and assign the result to a new column
df['url'] = df['Numbers'].map(numberToUrl)

# We can print the first 5 elements via:
df.head()
```

As you can see, it's extremely simple to pass a function to each row.
If you want to iterate over the rows you can do it like so:

```
for (index, row) in df['url'].iteritems():
    # Do your operations here
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
for (index, row) in df['url'].iteritems():
    uClient = uReq(row)
    page_html = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()

    page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
    # ...
```

### Additional notes

I would not recommend to use `urllib.request` directly. Instead you could use a wrapper library called [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

Comment: i'll just trying but i get the error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'" and i havn't locating the mistake so far.

Comment: It works like Anderssons script. Only the last result... I thing the problem is somewhere elso in my script. Thanks!!